# Change font to only section and subsection of my document

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I would change the font of `section` and `subsection` of my document. I have created it using `book` class. I would use this font:

[image]

According to Adobe pdf propriety, this font is AvantGarde-Demi. How can I use it in Latex. what command I should use to recreate this in latex. I think I should use `titlesec` package right?

Comment: A good place to start is the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)

Comment: According to Latex Font Catologue this found should correspond to AvantGarde

Comment: Yes, `titlesec` is the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `sectsty`

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{avant}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{pag} %% To make only sf fonts to be avant garde.
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\chapterfont{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont} %% for chapter if you want
\sectionfont{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont} %% Similarly for others. see the manual of sectsty, section 5.
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Event Monitor Pattern}
\subsection{Some sub-section}
\subsubsection{Some sub sub section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## With `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{avant}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{pag} %% To make only sf fonts to be avant garde.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\bfseries\Large}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\bfseries\Large}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Event Monitor Pattern}
\subsection{Some sub-section}
\subsubsection{Some sub sub section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is their a way to make this work with chalkduster-font?