# How to set chapter, section headings a specific font?

Tags: fonts, sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the font for a \section title (and chapter etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc)

The serif font`New TX times` is used for text. What if I want set the chapter, section headings a specific sans serif font. I know package `titlesec` can be used to set `\sffamily` such as:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}}
```

But how to set a desired sans font, e.g the sans font for all headings provided by:

```
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

In short, I want `times` be the text font, and `tgadventor sans` be the font for all headings.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc

Comment: Why changing `\familydefault`? `\usepackage{tgadventor}` is sufficient to say that `\sffamily` will use the TeX Gyre Adventor font.

Comment: See also: [Change font to only section and subsection of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94126)

Comment: Or simply use `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qag}` instead of `\usepackage{tgadventor}`.

Comment: Thank you all. Where can I find the  keyword xxx for use of `\fontfamily{xxx}` or `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{xxx}` ?

Comment: You can find it in the `fontname.sty` file. For example the file `tgadventor.sty` has the line `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qag}`. See also [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251)