# Using different fonts in a latex document

Tags: fonts, sectioning

The present state is:

- I get two ttf fonts, say `font1.ttf` and `font2.ttf`.
- I used autoinst tool to convert the both into latex usable fonts.

In my document preamble, now I'm able to use:

```
\usepackage{font1}
```

or

```
\usepackage{font2}
```

The question now is how (with or without this ability) to *redefine* fonts for chapter and section names with one of the font?

My first idea was to `\usepackage{font1}` to set a *main font* for the document and to `\usepackage{titlesec}` to format the section/chapter names with the other, but now I can't find how to make use of my font2 inside the `\titleformat` command

Comment: PS: Yes, I'm already reading texts about XeLaTex and LuaTex. And yes, I'm thinking about to make use of them. But for the first time, let us stay on the Latex base.

Comment: Use the family name of font2 `\fontfamily{name of font2}\selectfont`. Look in font2.sty to find the name.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: If that suggestion doesn't work, please post some more information about what you've done and what code you are using as it is pretty hard to say much otherwise. There is somewhere a question about using a different font for small amounts of text but I can't find it. (The search function here is extremely frustrating!)

Comment: Hello people, I found the solution just now, here: [stackexchange] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94126/change-font-to-only-section-and-subsection-of-my-document) thank you very much for commenting.